# Clarification about card.io models for character recognition

Tags: card.io

I started looking at card.io as part of a Android application that should to be able to scan a card and recognise the card number, date of expiration, card holder.

After digging for a while, I got to the card.io-dmz/models/generated folder where I see files that, according to a comment in their beginning, were "Autogenerated from models/conv/...".

However I was not able to find details about the files used to generate these "models". After checking the code, I assume that these generated files are directly responsible with the OCR of the numbers from cards.

To provide an example, the following card is scanned and recognised just fine (numbers only)

[image: Embossed card]

but the following card fails

[image: Non embossed card]

I tried adjusting the ROI before the vertical segmentation is done, but I think the differences between the font used on the 2 cards makes it impossible to scan the second card.

My question really is, given the current open source projects from git hub, are there any chances for someone to add the capability of scanning cards similar as the black one above, or this would require to have access to other resources used to perform the actual OCR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dave from card.io here.

@Adrian your conclusions are all correct.

While we'd love to extend our [deep-learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning) character-recognition models to cover newer style cards, such as your second card above, it's a big task.

Quite a few new-style cards (~100) would be required both to update the code that locates the card number in the first place, and then to train new character-recognition models.

At the moment, this isn't something that lends itself well to open sourcing. People tend to not want to share images of their credit cards, for some reason.

We have given some thought toward creating an open-source app that could be used to collect some portions of card images (e.g., all digit *positions*, plus actual images of just a few of the digits, plus an image of the expiration date). Then perhaps we could crowd-source a usefully large collection of information. And while that collection is being built, we could work on open-sourcing the many in-house tools we have created for working with computer vision and deep learning.

Would such a project be something you might participate in?

Comment: why dont you integrate tesseract with card.io